# VSCode Intellisense adding "={}" after grabbing existing variable in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My intellisense had been working fine.. but after a recent upgrade it seems like things have broken:

[image]

`classNames` is used as a function, and `filterBy` is a previously defined variable - I don't understand why intellisense has changed to all of the sudden add `=""` and `={}` when grabbing these previously defined variables.. is there configuration I need to change?

Comment: I've seen this question too many times these days, it looks like some kind of update or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing the [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) VSC extension.

You can also workaround this issue by changing the setting 'JSX Attribute Completion Style' to none.

Comment: thank you - I tried disabling the extension which didn't work for me.. but changing that setting to `none` did work!